# What's the difference between 1:1 roc and 1:N roc?

Tags: conv-neural-network, face-recognition

Indeed I know the difference between face verification and face identification. But still, is there a `1:N roc`, or any similar index to evaluate face identification?

Code examples are better!

Comment: you could find some success on the AI stack exchange site! it's in area 51 too!